# How to display the names in repeated cards

Tags: reactjs

I have fetched the data from an api using axios ,I want each data in a separate card using react and bootstrap.This is the code that i have tried.

`

```
const DisplayProjects = () => {
 const url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
 const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
axios.get(url).then((response) => setProjects(response.data));
}, []);

const projectDisplay = projects.map((project) => (
<h1 key={project.id}>{project.title}</h1>
));

return (
<div>
  <Layout>
    <h3>Projects </h3>

   
    <div className="container">
  
      
      <div className="card">
        <div className="contact-card">
          <Link>{projectDisplay}</Link>
        </div>
      </div>

      
    </div>
  </Layout>
</div>
  );
 };

export default DisplayProjects;
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get multiple cards repeated , you only need to use map function on your div of cards . In what you did you'll get multiple Links element inside of one card div :

Take a look at my sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/mapping-in-react-uh5ks

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


export default function App() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then((response) =>{
        // destructuring my data
        const { data } = response.data
        console.log(data)
        setProjects(data)
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>Projects </h3>

        <div className="container">
        {/* use map to go through your data and get multiple divs */}
        {
          projects && projects.map(project =>{
            return(
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="contact-card">
                      <li>{project.email}</li>
                  </div>
                </div>
            )
          })
        }
          
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the code is not clear and you don't understand some part feel free to ask .
*If it's answer your question , would you accept it please it's my first time to answer :) .*

**NB: Json placeholder api is broken this why i use another fake api generator**

Comment: Another one is can you pleas explain that projects&&projects.map. What it does?

Comment: @mayaj : " projects && projects " is an and operator , the way it's work is :

Comment: @mayaj : " projects && projects " is an and operator , the way it's work is : (if this part is true) && (this part will execute) . Why this is important , imagine that in api data , we have a user that doesn't have any email for example , you'll get an error because , you'll try to map on undefined . It will be [ undefined.map ] it will be an error . You can also change the and (&& )  operator by the conditionnal rendering .Here is a link to more understand the concept : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical-ampamp-operator